# WP-API get posts and order them by a descending order

Tags: wordpress, wp-api, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to grab posts and order them by date, in a descending order.

I am talking about this API: https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API

I tried:

`http://url.com/json/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[order]=DESC`

`http://url.com/json/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?order=desc`

Neither of them work.

But this, for example, works fine:

`http://url.com/json/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[cat]=3`

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure, it's not working? I've tried `http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?order=asc` and `http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?order=desc` - seems to be working fine. According to their docs, it should work: http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/posts/.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to use `orderby` e.g.

`http://url.com/json/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[orderby]=wpdb_fieldname&order=desc`

In your case

`http://url.com/json/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[orderby]=date&order=desc`

More details here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters